# How to install Docker on Tails

Tags: docker, tails-os

As far as I know, Tails is based on Debian. I tried to install Docker using the instruction for Debian. But it doesn't want to add the key

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ sudo apt-key adv \
>        --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
>        --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
[sudo] password for amnesia: 
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.JPiSwbg3oi --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
gpg: запрашиваю ключ 2C52609D с hkp сервера ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 6: Could not resolve host: ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: не найдено данных формата OpenPGP.
gpg: Всего обработано: 0
```

Comment: The Tails distro is aimed at protecting your anonymity - so many services and programs are unavailable or locked down more than on a standard distro to achieve this aim. I suspect that you're finding out that Docker requires some of these locked down features.

Comment: Also, it'd *probably* help if you showed the error message translated into English -- a lot fewer people speak Russian than English on here. That said, judging by the non-russian part your problem is that `gpgkeys` couldn't find the keyserver that's supposed to hold the public key you were trying to import, and thus it aborted.